# Error bars in Barchart with Graphics3D

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, charts

I have a problem with error bars in a 3d graphics. I wrote the following code to represent a matrix (called in the code "dataX":

```
xticks = 
  Table[{i, 
    If[Mod[i, 1] == 0.5, IntegerPart[i + 0.5], ""], {0, 0.01}}, {i, 
    0.5, 7.5, 1}];
yticks = 
  Table[{i, 
    If[Mod[i, 1] == 0.5, IntegerPart[i + 0.5], ""], {0, 0.01}}, {i, 
    0.5, 7.5, 1}];
zticks = 
 Table[{N[i/100], If[Mod[i, 2] == 0, NumberForm[i/100, {3, 2}], " "], 
   If[Mod[i, 2] == 0, {0, 0.01}, {0, 0.007}]}, {i, -8, 2, 0.5}]
BarChart3D[dataX, ChartLayout -> "Grid", BarSpacing -> {0, 0}, 
   ColorFunction -> ColorData[{"TemperatureMap", {-0.088, 0.088}}], 
   ColorFunctionScaling -> False, Canvas -> False, 
   ChartBaseStyle -> EdgeForm[{Opacity[1, Black], Thickness[.001]}], 
   FaceGrids -> All][[1]] // 
 Graphics3D[#, Axes -> True, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1/GoldenRatio}, 
   FaceGrids -> {{{0, -1, 
       0}, {{0, 2, 4, 6, 8}, {0, -0.02, -0.04, -0.06, -0.08}}}, {{1, 
       0, 0}, {{0, 2, 4, 6, 8}, {0, -0.02, -0.04, -0.06, -0.08}}}}, 
   Boxed -> False, AxesEdge -> {{1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {-1, -1}}, 
   Ticks -> {xticks, yticks, zticks}, PlotRangePadding -> 0, 
   LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 16, FontFamily -> "Sans-Serif", Black}, 
   ViewPoint -> {-19, 12, -8.5}, ViewVertical -> {0, 0, -1}] &
```

which gives me the following output:

[image]

Now I would like to add error bars. I found the following code may work, if I define the function:

```
stdErrorData = ConstantArray[0.01, {8, 8}]
chartData = 
 Table[dataX[[i, j]] -> stdErrorData[[i, j]], {i, 1, 8}, {j, 1, 8}]
errorBar3D[b : {{x0_, x1_}, {y0_, y1_}, {z0_, z1_}}, value_, meta_] :=
  Block[{error}, error = Flatten[meta];
  error = 
   If[error === {}, 0, 
    Last[error]]; {ChartElementDataFunction["Cube", "Profile" -> 2][
    b], {Black, Opacity[0.7], 
    Line[{{{(x0 + x1)/2, (y0 + y1)/2, 
        z1 - error}, {(x0 + x1)/2, (y0 + y1)/2, 
        z1 + error}}, {{1/4 (3 x0 + x1), (y0 + y1)/2, 
        z1 + error}, {1/4 (x0 + 3 x1), (y0 + y1)/2, 
        z1 + error}}, {{1/4 (3 x0 + x1), (y0 + y1)/2, 
        z1 - error}, {1/4 (x0 + 3 x1), (y0 + y1)/2, z1 - error}}}]}}]
```

and if I re-write Barchart3D as:

```
BarChart3D[chartData, ChartElementFunction -> errorBar3D, 
  ChartLayout -> "Grid", BarSpacing -> {0, 0}, 
  ColorFunction -> ColorData[{"TemperatureMap", {-0.088, 0.088}}], 
  ColorFunctionScaling -> False, Canvas -> False, 
  ChartBaseStyle -> EdgeForm[{Opacity[1, Black], Thickness[.001]}], 
  FaceGrids -> All][[1]]
```

(so basically replacing "dataX" with "chartData, ChartElementFunction -> errorBar3D".

This is what I get as an output:

[image]

Now, I have a problem with this:
I don't get why the colors and the style of my bars change, as I left all the parts specifying the color unchanged in the scope of Barchart3D? The problem seems to come from Graphics3D, as if I only plot Barchart3D I get the good colors that I specified.

If you can give me some hints it would be much appreciated. I think I don't undestand very well how the error function works.

EDIT:
After adding Neutral to Lightning in Graphics3D I got this result, which is pretty close to the original. I'm satisfied with the result, but it is different from the first one. I wonder why there is this discrepancy and how to recover the small glow and different lighting angle on the bars but I didn't find a solution yet.

[image]

Comment: add the option `Lighting -> "Neutral"` to `Graphics3D[...]`?

Comment: @kglr I did figure it out in the end but thanks a lot for answering! There is stil a small discrepancy between the results (see edit) that I'm trying to fix (if it's even possible) but I'm quite satisfied :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SeedRandom[1];

dataX = RandomReal[{-.03, .06}, {8, 8}] + 
   Reverse[ToeplitzMatrix[PadRight[{1, 1}, 8]]] RandomReal[{-.08, 0}, {8, 8}];

chartData = Map[Thread[# -> .01] &] @ dataX;

barchartoptions = {ImageSize -> 400,
   ChartLayout -> "Grid",
   BarSpacing -> {0, 0}, 
   ColorFunction -> ColorData[{"TemperatureMap", {-0.088, 0.088}}], 
   ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
   "Canvas" -> False, FaceGrids -> None, 
   ChartBaseStyle -> EdgeForm[{Opacity[1, Black], Thickness[.001]}],
   ViewPoint -> {-19, 12, -8.5},
   ViewVertical -> {0, 0, -1},
   Boxed -> False, 
   Axes -> False};
```

We first replicate the issue in OP:

```
BarChart3D[chartData, barchartoptions, 
 ChartElementFunction -> ToExpression[First@#], 
 PlotLabel -> Style[
    Column[{ChartElementFunction -> First[#], Last@#}, Center], 16]]& /@
    {{"Automatic", ""}, {"errorBar3D", "(\"Cube\")"}} // Row
```

[image]

The issue is caused by the `ChartElementDataFunction["Cube",...]` used in the definition of `errorBar3D`. If we replace it with `ChartElementDataFunction["FadingCube"]` we get the same styling of the bars as in the first chart. (Although I could not find any reference to it in the docs, `"FadingCube"` seems to be default `ChartElementFunction` for `BarChart3D`.)

So define a new function `errorBar3Db`:

```
DownValues[errorBar3Db] = DownValues[errorBar3D] /. 
  {errorBar3D -> errorBar3Db, 
  ChartElementDataFunction[__] -> ChartElementDataFunction["FadingCube"]};
```

Using `errorBar3Db` gives the same styling of bars as the original chart:

```
BarChart3D[chartData, barchartoptions, 
 ChartElementFunction -> ToExpression[First@#], 
 PlotLabel -> Style[
   Column[{ChartElementFunction -> First[#], Last@#}, Center], 16]]& /@
    {{"Automatic", ""}, {"errorBar3Db", "(\"FadingCube\")"}} // Row
```

[image]

#### Update:

A custom `ChartElementFunction` with customizable error-bars:

```
errorCube[cubeOpacity_ : Automatic, radius_ : .2, errorColor_ : Red] := 
  {ChartElementData["FadingCube"][##] /. 
   HoldPattern[VertexColors -> vc_] :> 
     Rule[VertexColors, Opacity[cubeOpacity /. Automatic -> .7, #] & /@ vc], 
   Blend[{{3/4, errorColor}, {1/4, Charting`ChartStyleInformation["Color"]}}], 
   FaceForm[Opacity[1]], EdgeForm[], 
   Table[ChartElementData["ErrorCube", "Shape" -> "Circle"][
     {{-radius, radius} + Mean@#, {-radius, radius} + Mean@#2, #3} & @@ #,
     {#2 + e}], {e, {1, -1} #3[[1]]}]} &;
```

***Examples:***

```
SeedRandom[1];
errors = RandomReal[{.005, .015}, {8, 8, 2}];

xDataWerrors = MapThread[Rule, {dataX, errors}, 2];

BarChart3D[xDataWerrors, barchartoptions, ChartElementFunction -> errorCube[]]
```

[image]

Replace `errorCube[]` with `errorCube[Automatic, .1, Black]` to get

[image]

Use `` errorCube[Automatic, .3, Charting`ChartStyleInformation["Color"]] `` to get

[image]

Comment: Wow, thank you so much for the solution and for all the examples! I spent a lot of time trying to fix the issue but I didn't find "fadingcube", I was growing really frustrated. Thank you!